# How to latinise the French first name Giraud?

Tags: names, french, latinization

In a previous question [Geraldus vs Giraudus](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18733/geraldus-vs-giraudus) I asked  what would the Latin equivalent of Gerald.
One on the answer suggested that it would be different (that is that Giraudus would be an option) if I asked how to Latinise the name Giraud.

Comment: Rimbaud might provide an analogy. The French adjective for Rimbaud is “rimbaldien”. This is some evidence for correlation between “aud” in French and “ald” in Latin.

Answer (score 4):

The latin form of **Giraudus** seems to be well attested in older and modern use, e.g.:

- [Joseph Donatus Giraudus Cuneensis ad sacræ facultatis pro-doctoratum](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zz1W6krDsUEC&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)...
- [Cultures of Power](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rdeU1TQWQjYC&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=giraudus&source=bl&ots=KbGVZmxuvA&sig=ACfU3U0IAFymsKMmEODFHRnCsnwPNnXUCA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGu-SLv_j5AhXDlFwKHUoLB2M4ChDoAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=giraudus&f=false), page 121
- [GIRALDUS de Cornossa](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/giraldus-de-cornossa_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27-Arte-Medievale%29/) (ld variant but also mentions *Giraudus* as a synonym)
- [Giraudus de Morech](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giraudus_de_Morech)
- and [Giraudus, Dictionary of Medieval Names from European Sources](https://dmnes.org/cite/Giraudus/1123/CartYonne1)